# Is it possible to auto-fill a file input field on a home server?

Tags: javascript, security

With JavaScript, it is quite easy to have an <input> element automatically take on a value once the page has loaded, so long as its **type** attribute is not "file"; this makes perfect sense, of course, given that auto-submitting a form containing sensitive data to a server is a single line of code away.

However, on a home server (WAMP, if it's at all helpful), this threat is eradicated entirely. So, is there by chance a way to bypass a file input field's default behavior in a situation where the risk is effectively zero?

Comment: Why not just use an upload directory since its on your home server anyway? Just drop the file(s) in there and process them that way.

Comment: While the iMacros plugin for Firefox you suggested seems rather promising, I'm much more comfortable with a browser-agnostic solution (primarily because Opera is so awesome) and so decided to do it the way you suggested here; worked like a charm. Just a matter of directory walking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863) lets you set up little "browser automation" scripts that might do what you want.